# Does Hibernate support mapping of a collection of strings to a column with comma (or any other character) separated string

Tags: java, hibernate

The common approach to maintaining of one to many relationships in RDB is using two tables joined by a key. I'm trying to avoid creation of an additional table.
Does Hibernate support mapping of a String collection to a column in the same table as the entity?

Comment: No, unless you define a custom type (or a JPA 2.1 converter) that does it. Read the Hibernate documentation to know how. You could also do that transformation in the getter and setter of the property.

Comment: it would be preferable to use a custom type for this. doing the transform in the getters/setters risks tricking hibernate into thinking the object is dirty when it isn't. but using this to avoid creating an intersection table sounds really ugly. You can't index it.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't use calls to getters/setters to determine if an entity is dirty. It takes snapshots and compares them.

Comment: I am probably confusing this with something else. if it's only 1-to-many can't you put a FK reference to the parent on the child (and avoid adding the intersection table)? or is this a misstatement and you meant many-to-many? concatenating the keys in one field means you can't use indexes or use RI constraints.